# Expression Tree 'Any' on Collection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, expression-trees

I'm trying to determine if any of the objects in the collection have the target property set to true. How can I accomplish this? Here's what I have so far:

```
public class AnyValidAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private static MethodInfo AnyMethod =
        typeof(Enumerable)
          .GetMethods()
          .First(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2));

    string booleanPropertyToCheck;
    Type entityType;

    public AnyValidAttribute(string booleanPropertyToCheck, Type entityType)
    {
        this.booleanPropertyToCheck = booleanPropertyToCheck;
        this.entityType = entityType;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var collection = new List<object>((IEnumerable<object>)value);
        var propInfo = this.entityType.GetProperty(this.booleanPropertyToCheck);
        var param = Expression.Parameter(this.entityType, "entity");
        var property = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, propInfo);
        var trueValue = Expression.Constant(true);
        var comparison = Expression.Equal(property, trueValue);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(comparison, param);
        var call = Expression.Call(AnyMethod, comparison, lambda);
        var anyTrue = ???

        return true ? null : new ValidationResult("At least one is required.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to know more about the objects in your collection - can you, for example, make them implement an interface that has the property you want to check?

Comment: They are all view models, Tomas. The attribute should be able to be used on any collection. I went with Maksim's suggestion. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to call dynamically `Any`  method?

I would suggest to do somehting like this:

```
var anyDelegate = lambda.Compile();
var genericMethod = AnyMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType);
var anyTrue = (bool)genericMethod.Invoke(null, new[] {value, genericMethod});
```

You don't really need your `Call` Expression.

Complete call inside of your method would be like (works for me in Linqpad):

```
var propInfo = this.entityType.GetProperty(this.booleanPropertyToCheck);

var param = Expression.Parameter(this.entityType, "entity");
var property = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, propInfo);
var trueValue = Expression.Constant(true);
var comparison = Expression.Equal(property, trueValue);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(comparison, param);  

var anyDelegate = lambda.Compile();

var genericMethod = AnyMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType);
var anyTrue = (bool)genericMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { value, anyDelegate });
```